# C# How to parse json data without key name?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have json string like this:

```
{"fields":[{"type":"none","options":["option1","option2","option3"]}]}
```

I'm using JObject to parse json data. I can parse data that has name, like type, etc. But how can I parse data that doesn't have a name, like option1, option2 and option3? Here is my code:

```
JObject object = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var type = object["fields"][0]["type"].ToString();
```

but problem is with options.

Comment: As an aside, it's helpful if you can post real, compilable code - you can't use `object` as an identifier. If you had posted a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, it would have been easier to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `options` is just an array of values - like `fields` is. But each value in there is just a string, rather than a further map of key/value pairs.

So you could use:

```
string firstOption = (string) jsonObject["fields"][0]["options"][0];
```

If you want the whole set of options as a `List<string>`, you can use:

```
var options = jsonObject["fields"][0]["options"]
    .Select(option => (string) option)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried that. I get null reference exception.

Comment: @Matthew: Well with the exact JSON you've given, the code I've provided works fine. So I suspect you've got a typo there, or your JSON doesn't actually look like that.

Comment: Thank you, your code was working fine. I deleted other part of code so I got exception at that line.

Answer (score 2):

```
string jsonString = @"{""fields"":[{""type"":""none"",""options"":[""option1"",""option2"",""option3""]}]}";

var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var options = obj["fields"][0]["options"].ToList();
```